# ExtJS sorterFn issue

Tags: javascript, extjs, grid

I have a grid which I want to be sorted by status. But a row with a specific cell value should be shown on top, so I read the docs and changed the example to this:

```
sorterFn: function(rec, id) {
            var checkForOwnConnections = function(o) {
                var values = [],
                    _idns = [],
                    _id = VPN.config.Userdata.username;
                rec.locks().each(function(lock) {
                    values.push(lock.get('idn'));
                });
                _idns = Ext.unique(values);
                if (_idns.indexOf(_id) > -1) {
                    console.log('Show this on top');
                    return 1;
                } else {
                    return 2;
                }

            },
                connVal1 = checkForOwnConnections(rec),
                connVal2 = checkForOwnConnections(id);

            if (connVal1 === connVal2) {
                return 0;
            }

            return connVal1 < connVal2 ? -1 : 1;
        }
```

My console logs 'Show this on top' as expected, but my grid is not sorted correctly. Could anyone tell me, where my mistake is?

Comment: I'm receiving data through a PHP-API and I'm following the MVC architecture, so I don't how to build such a fiddle. But you could compare it to this one I found: [link](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/143) It's almost the same code and it's working. The point that my console logs correctly also shows, that the data is received correctly, so I don't know why my code doesn't work...

Comment: I'm receiving data through an ajax-call. So how should my code look like to work?

Comment: I really do not know who is `rec` and `id`: in a sorterFn both are records... besides `locks()` seems to be undocumented. Is that your own function? If yes, how do you expect us to understand that?

Comment: `rec` is the data record, `id` is an unused param (just in case a second param is needed to work). locks() is a function that got created when importing data with an 1:n relationship (if I understood that correctly - I got it from a snippet I found).

Comment: `id` is an unused parameter? Take a look in your code! Some (unrelated) tips: learn debugging (in JS) and read the documentation (ExtJS')

Comment: well, the two parameters should be the objects being compared, but in fact, I just want to check if my grid row contains a specific value. I also tried `VPN.config.Userdata.username` and `rec` as parameters, but it still didn't work...

Comment: Btw, returning 2 doesn't make sense.  [According to the API](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.util.Sorter-cfg-sorterFn), you should return -1, 0, or 1.

Comment: I also thought this, but why does [this](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/143) fiddle work then? @incutonez

Comment: Ah, ok.  I was reading your code wrong... you're not actually returning 2 from the sorterFn.  My bad.  I cannot say why your code isn't working because like Andrei said, you've got some custom code in there that we can't see.  I am going to assume that all of your lines are returning 1 in `checkForOwnConnections`, therefore, the sorterFn always returns 0, which means every line will be sorted as if there was no sort applied.

Comment: the fact, that code like `console.log('anything')` inside the `if (_idns.indexOf(_id) > -1)` block is being executed, let's me assume, that the statement itself is true in some cases. I logged different variables, and the value of `_inds` in fact equals `_id`. So there has to be something wrong with the return values in `checkForOwnConnections` or the sorting behaviour in `return connVal1 < connVal2 ? -1 : 1;`